# calculating Area inside intersection of circle and ellipse using line integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, greens-theorem

> Consider a circle parametrized as $(r\cos (t), r \sin (t))$ and an ellipse parametrized as $(a\cos (t), b \sin (t))$.
> Assuming that $a>r>b$, you find the area of region of intersection of circle and elipse by setting up line integral and using greens theorem.

I tried to parametrize those four curves (boundary of the region). For the left and right region, $r$ is fixed but couldn't find $θ$. For upper and lower curves, both $r$ and $θ$ are varying.
Are there other ways to approach this problem?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I tried to parametrize those four curves (boundary of the region). For the left and right region ,$r$ is fixed but couldn't find $\theta$. For upper and lower curves, both $r$ and $\theta$ are varying.

Comment: What’s shaded area？PS: can this be done by finding intersecting points and then do integral of difference between two functions?

Comment: @CharlieChang I want to use green's theorem somehow. I don't want to use  double integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Green's theorem area bounded by curve $C$ (as I guess $b<r<a$) can be calculated as:
$$S=\int\limits_Cxdy=-\int\limits_Cydx=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_C(xdy-ydx)$$

1)

Intersection points can be calculated as
$$\begin{array}{}
x^2=a^2\frac{r^2-b^2}{a^2-b^2} \\
y^2=b^2\frac{a^2-r^2}{a^2-b^2}
\end{array}
$$
So we have 4 symmetrical point with argument in first quadrant
$$\tan (\phi_0) = \frac{b}{a}\sqrt{\frac{a^2-r^2}{r^2-b^2}}$$
From obtained curve $C$ is ellipse on $[\phi_0, \pi-\phi_0]$ and $[\pi+\phi_0, 2\pi-\phi_0]$ and is circle on remained part of $[0,2\pi]$. Now integral can be divided in 4 summands and each part separately can be parametrized by polar or extended polar coordinates.

2)
Sweet in the end: possibly it is more easy to calculate ellipse parts outside of circle, then subtract from ellipse area. Obtained subtract from circle area. So you'll need calculate only integral on $[-\phi_0, \phi_0]$ more then ellipse and less then circle. As suggested by  Charlie Chang it's more easy by double integral, but as you insist on Green, then everything needed you have.